# how to handle HTML image click events in android

Tags: android, html, css

I have to create an HTML page which have more than one images. If User clicks on any image then I have to show full view of open gallery in android. I am able to create galley in android. But I cannot understand how to handle button click in html so that It will give call back to my android gallery activity.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to answer of [get the click event from webpage in my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907439/get-the-click-event-from-webpage-in-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

See the `Binding JavaScript code to Android code` section, you can bind JavaScript event to  Android code:)