# get the click event from webpage in my Android application

Tags: java, javascript, android

I'm creating a sample webpage with button..this webpage am calling in Android using webview.

now when I click the button on webpage(that is html button). I should be able to execute some codes in Android..

How to proceed?

```
public class web extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webdisplay);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://localhost/test.html");
        valid = new Button(ctx);
        valid.setOnClickListener(this);
        refuse = new Button(ctx);
        refuse.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Button is a html element or Button in Android ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We can detect following HTML elements as per Android API Document.

```
int     ANCHOR_TYPE     HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag
int     EDIT_TEXT_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an edit text area
int     EMAIL_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an email address
int     GEO_TYPE    HitTestResult for hitting a map address
int     IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE   HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag which contains HTML::img
int     IMAGE_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting an HTML::img tag
int     PHONE_TYPE  HitTestResult for hitting a phone number
int     SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE     HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag with src=http
int     SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE   HitTestResult for hitting a HTML::a tag with src=http + HTML::img
int     UNKNOWN_TYPE    Default HitTestResult, where the target is unknown
```

I think you will be able to get all events using WebView's setOnTouchListener function.

WebView has inner class named [HitTestResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html). 
HitTestResult class will help us to find the HTML element which press when user click on WebView.

[HitTestResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html) class has only two method.

1. getExtra() : It return String. String has HTML element which is clicked by user
2. getType() : It return integer. It is used to identify which HTML element is clicked by user.

You can do like :

```
wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

            Log.i(TAG, "getExtra = "+ hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Edited :**
Refer for perfect answer :
[Detect click on HTML button through javascript in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview)

Comment: i will have a check and i doubt..suppose there are two button..how will identity whether its from button1 or buton2

Comment: what do you want when user clicks on button ? starting a new activity !

Comment: Hey I got another way dude : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview

Comment: valid = new Button(ctx); what is ctx?am in activity now

Comment: it must be : valid = new Button(this);