# Open a dialog box from button click of a html page in webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I had a query to use something like the question says .
I am displaying a html file through a WEBVIEW in my android application , which has a button on it.
I am unable to figure out the onClick event for this button. As i want to open a new dialog box

Any help will be helpful
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview).
You'll find your answer there.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [get the click event from webpage in my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907439/get-the-click-event-from-webpage-in-my-android-application)