# Get parent html element on click

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I have an app, that has an `Activity` with `WebView`. I'm looking for a way to get parent html element when user clicks `WebView`.

For instance: user goes to web-site, clicks some text block and I want to get `div`, that contains this text block. Is it possible? I found class `WebView.HitTestResult` in the docs, but seems like it only can to retrieve anchor and image tags.

Comment: alternatively you can parse the site by JSOUP and then manually search for the necessary flow

Comment: @gabber The problem is that I need the element, that user clicks on. It may be not only div, but other tags too. It is like Firefox inspector feature (for developers). When you hover over some html element, it shows it's boundaries. I need to reach similar behaviour. I don't need to highligh element, but retrieve it with all attributes.

Comment: maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907439/get-the-click-event-from-webpage-in-my-android-application

Comment: @gabber Thank you. I've already encountered this question. Using this methods you can only detect clicks on images or anchors.